# What is the equivalent of Window's autorun, startup folder, for Xfce, Unity?

Tags: 12.04, 11.10, unity, xfce, autostart

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to start applications at startup automatically in Unity?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/48321/how-to-start-applications-at-startup-automatically-in-unity)

I need to start some programs after the desktop environment loads itself, what would be the equivalent of Window's autorun or Startup folder?